# Qual a diferença entre os métodos quit e exit do qApp?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Estou testando o exemplo [Getting Started Programming with Qt Widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html) e encontrei uma chamada de um método para sair da aplicação:

```
void Notepad::on_quitButton_clicked()
{
    qApp->quit();
}
```

Dei uma olhada nos outros métodos e encontrei um que faz aparentemente a mesma coisa:

```
qApp->exit();
```

Qual a diferença entre estes dois métodos e quando eu devo usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 2):

> A variável qApp é um ponteiro global que se refere ao único objeto
>   aplicação. É equivalente ao ponteiro retornado pela função
>   `QCoreApplication::instance()`, exceto que, em aplicações GUI, é um
>   ponteiro para uma instância de `QApplication`.
>   http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#qApp

Sendo `qApp` uma instância de `QCoreApplication`, uma das diferenças é que o método `quit` é um `SLOT`, ou seja, pode ser usado em resposta a um sinal do Qt.

[Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

Outra diferenças entre os métodos é que o `quit` sempre retorna 0 (zero), ao passo que o método `exit` pode receber um número inteiro para retornar um código diferente.

[void QCoreApplication::quit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit)

[void QCoreApplication::exit(int returnCode = 0)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#exit)

Ou seja, ambos os métodos devem ser usados quando a aplicação deve ser fechada, mas o `quit`, que não permite atribuição de código de erro, pode ser usado diretamente em conexão com um sinal, e o `exit`, que permite atribuição de código de erro, só pode ser usado da forma convencional.